# In Javascript, if you have a function can you get the arguments by name?

Tags: javascript

Let's say you have

```
var funct=function(a,b){
    return a+b;
};
console.log(funct);
```

Is there any way you can get the names of the arguments (a and b) from funct?  If you are with in the function do you have any access to them?  I know "arguments" gives you an array-like object, but is there anything that gives you a map-like or object-like representation of the arguments so that you can get their names when the function was declared?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: You can already access the arguments to a function by name by using the actual names – it's probably best to use the `argument` object to implement variadic functions. If you want dynamic named arguments, use the options-hash pattern. (The one jQuery and other libraries use pervasively.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to turn the function into a string and parse it out

```
var funct=function(a,b){
    return a+b;
};
var re = /\(([^)]*)/;
var daArgs = funct.toString().match(re)[1].split(/,\s?/);
console.log(daArgs);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9DxLZ/)

Still have no clue why you would need it.

Comment: I assumed he wanted the argument names *inside* the function, not *outside*.

Comment: @Rocket Than replace `funct.toString()` with the deprecated `arguments.callee.toString()`, but it will not run in strict mode. :)

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot do this.  There's no way to get the name of variable as a string.

If you really need this, I suggest instead of passing multiple parameters, pass an object.

```
var funct=function(args){
    var argsNames = Object.keys(args); // Get the keys of the args object
    console.log(argsNames); // ['a','b']
    return args.a + args.b;
};
```

Then call it like so:

```
funct({
    a: 12,
    b: 2
});
```

Comment: could make use of object.keys this way as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir: What are you talking about?

Comment: @sherlocken: Thanks, I'll add that to the answer.